# Proving a 2-connected graph contains cycles (is my proof correct?)

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, graph-connectivity

My attempt at a proof is:

Let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph. Since $G$ is $2$-connected, $G$ contains no bridges - otherwise, we could pick an arbitrary bridge, remove one of its ends, and render $G$ disconnected - this contradicts $G$'s $2$-connectivity. Recall that an edge is a bridge, if and only if it does not lie on a cycle. Since $G$ contains no bridges, all of its edges must lie on some cycle, and hence, $G$ contains at least one cycle.

Is this the correct idea? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good, but note that removing one end of a bridge only disconnects the graph if there are other vertices on that side of the bridge. (This is ok because there must be other vertices on at least one side.)

Comment: Of course; then adding 'otherwise, we could pick an arbitrary bridge $e = (v, u)$, pick an end of $e$ that is connected to at least one other vertex $w$, remove that end, and render $G$ disconnected' would make this more explicit?

Comment: Yes, that would make it clear.